# how to configure/design a table with 30,000 insertion in every 15 minutes?

Tags: mysql, database-design, bulkinsert, query-performance

I am trying to design a database table which will be going to face 30,000 insertion in every 15 minutes. So this tables going to face millions of insertion.

A sample table is as follow-

```
CREATE TABLE `cdr` (`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                `dataPacketDownLink` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
                `dataPacketUpLink` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
                `dataPlanEndTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
                `dataPlanStartTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
                `dataVolumeDownLink` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
                `dataVolumeUpLink` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,  
                `dataplan` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  
                `dataplanType` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  
                `createdOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,  
                `deviceName` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,  
                `duration` int(11) NOT NULL,  
                `effectiveDuration` int(11) NOT NULL,  
                `hour` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  
                `eventDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,  
                `msisdn` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,  
                `quarter` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  
                `validDays` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  
                `dataLeft` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,  
                `completedOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,   
            PRIMARY KEY (`id`),   
            KEY `msisdn_index` (`msisdn`),   
            KEY `eventdate_index` (`eventDate`)   
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=55925171 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

How I can retrieve records if use comparison >= in case of date column(result in millions of record).
So please help me to design such table, so i can use optimized select statements without effecting insertion operation(lot of indexes create problem for insertion after millions of records).
Thank you.

Comment: I'd really try and avoid using the MyISAM engine. If something happens during one of these big inserts, the table doesn't have a journal and might end up irrecoverably scrambled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short answer:

1. Decide how do you want to keep history.
2. Use InnoDB engine.
3. Use partitioning to  manage data in chunks easily and fast.
4. Implement current window partitioning - have one table for current set and 1 or more tables for archives and move partitions to older tables.
5. For fastest write performance - remove all indexes and constrains. Cast them after all data is loaded. If there is no pressure on data insertion - leave them, but know what will be the penalty.
6. Ensure you server can handle so many connections / data volume. Plan for next 2-3 years as hardware upgrades take a lot of time.
7. Do load testing, including overloading - know your limits.

And keep researching.

Comment: hii stoleg,
>Use partitioning to manage data & remove all indexes and constrains.
partition also require unique key constraint, what i can do in that case? and I also have to read data from this table, which will need index. So how i can design?
I have read on other pages of stakeoverflow, people have tables with 400 Millions records and they are managing it. But I am not eligible to comment there so i can ask them :(

Comment: Yes you can manage even billion records. Tell more about the usage of the table, kind of queries you anticipate. You may consider using staging table for faster instert, but some delay for these record appearing in queried table. Or create a separate repoting table with aggrigates or most recent / often needed info to speed to limit number of rows queried, at cost of extra disk space and time.

Comment: queries like - 
    select c.msisdn,sum(c.dataVolumeDownLink+c.dataVolumeUpLink) as     datasum from cdr c where c.eventDate>='date_var' group by c.msisdn     order by datasum desc; 
mostly queried on eventdate with comparison. so tell me what should i do staging or reporting table or go with this one with slight changes.

Comment: To speed up aggregate queries you create a table with these aggregates calculated. Then you get the sum with straight `select` query without `sum()` and `group by`.

Comment: well this new table sounds great, do me one more favor, please give me a example or sample, how i can make it. I appreciate your help.

Comment: `insert into my_summary_table select key_field_1, key_field_2, ... , key_field_N, sum(measure_1), ..., sum (measure_N) from my_big_table where <look only at data not yet present in my_summary_table> group by ....`